# What is Objective C equivalent of openssl_sign from PHP?

Tags: php, objective-c, encryption

I need to create a sign of a string. I have a working code in PHP:

```
function buildSign($toSign, $key) {
    $signature = null;

    $pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($key);
    openssl_sign($toSign, $signature, $pkeyid);
    openssl_free_key($pkeyid);

    return base64_encode($signature);
}
```

How can I create an equivalent of this function in objective c?

I tried this code

```
- (NSString*) signString:(NSString*)string key:(NSString *)key {
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSData *hmac = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                          length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
    return [hmac base64EncodedString];
}
```

But it returns a very short string like this: `zM5GPdSiDooWSm78fLCdTnw1LHQ=`.

I need a long sign like this:

```
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
```

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 creates a 20 byte hash of the input. HMAC-SHA1 returns the SHA-1 output and in this case a BASE64 encoded string representation. But HSA-1 should no longer be used, instead use SHA-256 or SHA-512, these return 32 or 64 bytes.

But that is not what you need inorder to match the PHP code which is using the private key or a key pair to sign with the OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1 algorithm.

While Apple does not supply a pre-compiled version of OpenSSL you can get the source and compile it yourself.